# reorganize array to array of arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to insert arrays into array, for example I have

```
var objList = [
  {
    name: jack,
    status: ''
  },
  {
    name: mark,
    status: yes
  },
  {
    name: erik, 
    status: no
  },
  {
    name: mike,
    status: yes
  },
  {
    name: chaze,
    status: no
  }
]
```

what I want is everytime that it finds 'status:yes' it will push it to new array with the following 'status:or'. it would look something like this

```
[[{name: jack, status: ''}], [{name: mark, status: yes},{name: erik, status: no}], [{name: mike, status: yes},{name: chaze, status: no}]]
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Seems like just looping over your array and then applying your logic would simply solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array and check if the status is `yes`, then add a new sub array to the result set. Then just add the object to the last array.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'jack', status: '' }, { name: 'mark', status: 'yes' }, { name: 'erik', status: 'no' }, { name: 'mike', status: 'yes' }, { name: 'chaze', status: 'no' }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r.length || o.status === 'yes') {
            r.push([]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I'm looking for. Will mark it as correct answer :)

Comment: It might be cleaner to start with `[[]]` and skip the `length` check.  I suppose that might not be right if the data is empty, but it certainly feels a bit cleaner.